# Google Storage client library (appengine-gcs-client) has unavailable dependency (google-http-client-parent:pom:1.24.1)

Tags: java, maven, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I add appengine-gcs-client to my Google AppEngine Standard project with this:

```
    *<dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.appengine.tools</groupId>
        <artifactId>appengine-gcs-client</artifactId>
        <version>0.7</version>
    </dependency>*
```

(following instructions on this page: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/googlecloudstorageclient/setting-up-cloud-storage)

Compiling the project throws the following error (there was no problem few days ago):

*[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project myproject2: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.myproject2:myproject2:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies at com.google.appengine.tools:appengine-gcs-client:jar:0.7 -> com.google.api-client:google-api-client-appengine:jar:1.24.1 -> com.google.oauth-client:google-oauth-client-appengine:jar:1.24.1 -> com.google.http-client:google-http-client-appengine:jar:1.24.1: Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.google.http-client:google-http-client-appengine:jar:1.24.1: Failure to find com.google.http-client:google-http-client-parent:pom:1.24.1 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]*

It seems Google has just created some error in the dependent tree.

Is there any way I can fix it, even just a temporarily workaround?

---

Updating my question with the full pom that reproduces the error:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <groupId>com.myproject2</groupId>
    <artifactId>myproject2</artifactId>

    <properties>
        <appengine.maven.plugin.version>1.3.1</appengine.maven.plugin.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.showDeprecation>true</maven.compiler.showDeprecation>
    </properties>

    <prerequisites>
        <maven>3.3.9</maven>
    </prerequisites>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Compile/runtime dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
            <artifactId>appengine-api-1.0-sdk</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.59</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- For cloud storage https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/googlecloudstorageclient/setting-up-cloud-storage -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.appengine.tools</groupId>
            <artifactId>appengine-gcs-client</artifactId>
            <version>0.7</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Test Dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.endpoints</groupId>
            <artifactId>endpoints-framework</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.objectify</groupId>
            <artifactId>objectify</artifactId>
            <version>6.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <!-- for hot reload of the web application -->
        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}/WEB-INF/classes</outputDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>versions-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>display-dependency-updates</goal>
                            <goal>display-plugin-updates</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
                <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${appengine.maven.plugin.version}</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: First delete the directory in `$HOME/.m2/repository/com/google` and try to rebuild but I recommend to do this on plain command line...

Comment: Thanks khmarbaise. I just did that, but it doesn't help; the error symptom remains unchanged

Comment: Are you using Java 8 or Java 7?

Comment: Have you taken a look into `$HOME/.m2/repository/com/google/`? Do you find files there? Can you post the full pom file you are using ?

Comment: I'm facing the same. @David, did you find a solution?

Comment: I also have this problem as of this morning.   downgrading the gcs-client to 0.4 works for me as a temporary solution

Comment: @khmarbaise, I don't see those files in my local repository. I just updated my post with full pom file above.

Comment: @Jean: I'm using Java8;

Comment: @aaron_stasis thanks for workaround; that makes the above compiling error go away, but running the app now throws back a bunch of warnings  "invalid LOC header (bad signature)"

Comment: This is the client for Java 8 https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-java. The client you are using is for Java 7

Comment: Mine happens because of mapreduce and the build ends with the following error. Could not resolve dependencies for project PerpuleSmartShoppee:PerpuleSmartShoppee:war:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies at com.google.appengine.tools:appengine-mapreduce:jar:0.9 -> com.google.appengine.tools:appengine-gcs-client:jar:0.4.3 -> com.google.api-client:google-api-client-appengine:jar:1.24.1 -> com.google.oauth-client:google-oauth-client-appengine:jar:1.24.1 -> com.google.http-client:google-http-client-appengine:jar:1.24.1

Comment: Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.google.http-client:google-http-client-appengine:jar:1.24.1: Failure to find com.google.http-client:google-http-client-parent:pom:1.24.1 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced

Comment: Any solution to the above?

Comment: Thanks @Jean for pointing that out. appengine-gcs-client lib was fine with Java8 for me for a long time now. It only started having problem since yesterday. Anyway, I just tried switching to the lib for Java8 as you mentioned. The compiling error is gone, but now the AppEngine project doesn't work any; running it on my devbox with "mvn appengine:run" throws a lot of error: "java.lang.RuntimeException: Error scanning entry com/google/api/SystemParameterRule$1.class from jar file:///...-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT/WEB-INF/lib/proto-google-common-protos-1.12.0.jar and invalid LOC header (bad signature)"

Comment: 1.24.1 was just released yesterday.. looks like maven2 repository not up to date (yet)

Comment: What I don't get is how this version snuck into our dependency trees.  We're not using snapshots.. so.. did someone do 'the bad thing' and update an existing version??

Comment: ah.. the problem is that app engine-gcs-client-0.6 GAVE A RANGE of versions [1.19.0, 2.0].. and we all just got screwed by that.

Answer (score 4):

Seems like Google has done some renaming (they dropped the "-appengine" part of the artifactIds) that doesn't work in the 1.24.1 versions. Try replacing your gcs dependency with the following:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.appengine.tools</groupId>
    <artifactId>appengine-gcs-client</artifactId>
    <version>0.7</version>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>com.google.http-client</groupId>
      <artifactId>*</artifactId>
    </exclusion> 
  </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.http-client</groupId>
  <artifactId>google-http-client-appengine</artifactId>
  <version>1.23.0</version>
</dependency>
```

It will exclude all the non-working dependencies with the 1.24.1 version and instead use the previous 1.23.0. You may finally need to force maven to update remote dependencies with the "-U" flag e.g.,

```
mvn -U package
```

Comment: This, together with delete all of my local maven repository, worked for me. Thanks @user1362526!

Answer (score 3):

I was facing the error with appengine-mapreduce dependency.
Got it fixed by excluding the dependencies that were throwing the error.

Original Map reduce dependency

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.appengine.tools</groupId>
            <artifactId>appengine-mapreduce</artifactId>
            <version>0.9</version>
</dependency>
```

Error that was showing up

> Could not resolve dependencies for project
>   PerpuleSmartShoppee:PerpuleSmartShoppee:war:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Failed to
>   collect dependencies at
>   com.google.appengine.tools:appengine-mapreduce:jar:0.9 ->
>   com.google.appengine.tools:appengine-gcs-client:jar:0.4.3 ->
>   com.google.api-client:google-api-client-appengine:jar:1.24.1 ->
>   com.google.oauth-client:google-oauth-client-appengine:jar:1.24.1 ->
>   com.google.http-client:google-http-client-appengine:jar:1.24.1: Failed
>   to read artifact descriptor for
>   com.google.http-client:google-http-client-appengine:jar:1.24.1:
>   Failure to find
>   com.google.http-client:google-http-client-parent:pom:1.24.1 in
>   https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local
>   repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update
>   interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced ->

Got it changed to the following which got the build working

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-api-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.22.0</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>guava-jdk5</artifactId>
                    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
                <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
                <artifactId>google-api-client-appengine</artifactId>
                <version>1.22.0</version>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
                        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>   
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.google.appengine.tools</groupId>
                <artifactId>appengine-gcs-client</artifactId>
                <version>0.3</version>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
                        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
            </dependency>
              <dependency>
                <groupId>com.google.appengine.tools</groupId>
                <artifactId>appengine-mapreduce</artifactId>
                <version>0.9</version>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
                        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
                    </exclusion>
                    <exclusion>
                        <artifactId>appengine-gcs-client</artifactId>
                        <groupId>com.google.appengine.tools</groupId>
                    </exclusion>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
                        <artifactId>google-api-client</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
                        <artifactId>google-api-client-appengine</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>

                </exclusions>
            </dependency>
```

Answer (score 3):

Trying running it again.  Google didn't push the complete update to the library when they updated the maven versions yesterday.  They have since pushed the missing piece and it should now work correctly without any modifications.

Comment: Thanks Brian! Yes, I just removed the workaround described in answers below, and it works again.

Answer (score 2):

Yesterday, Google apparently failed to deploy version 1.24.0 for the parent of their com.google.http-client library.

[image]

They also used the undesirable practice of declaring a range for their http client dependency in [appengine-gcs-client](https://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=com/google/appengine/tools/appengine-gcs-client/0.6/appengine-gcs-client-0.6.pom) pom:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.http-client</groupId>
  <artifactId>google-http-client</artifactId>
  <version>[1.19.0,2.0)</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.http-client</groupId>
  <artifactId>google-http-client-jackson2</artifactId>
  <version>[1.19,2.0)</version>
</dependency>
```

So when they deployed a new version 1.24.0 yesterday, the transitive dependency upgraded automatically, but the version is an invalid deployment causing a failure.

This solved it for me:

```
       <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.appengine.tools</groupId>
            <artifactId>appengine-gcs-client</artifactId>
            <version>0.6</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.google.http-client</groupId>
                    <artifactId>google-http-client-jackson2</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.google.http-client</groupId>
                    <artifactId>google-http-client</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.http-client</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-http-client-jackson2</artifactId>
            <version>1.23.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.http-client</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-http-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.23.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try MavenUpdate -

Force update
Tick --- checkbox ReleasesForceUpdate of snapshots/Releases